# How can check exist "\" in a string vba?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code , but it not working:
[image]

```
strText = oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Text
If InStr(strText, "\") > 0 Then
    bPrice = True       
End If
```

How can check exist "\" in a string?

Comment: You want to check \ or currency symbol?

Comment: I want check 2 both? text exist or set currency.

Comment: try this  `If InStr(strText, "¥", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(strText, "\", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then`

Comment: value  "¥" can't copy to vba,

Comment: use Ascii as below shown by @Jeeped

Comment: It still not ok,If InStr(strText, Chr(165), vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(strText, "\", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **¥** is ASCII 165 dec. Try,

```
strText = oSheet.Cells(1, 1).Text
If cbool(InStr(1, strText, ChrW(165))) Then
    bPrice = True       
End If
```

Here's a test to make sure you are getting the right ASCII dec code. With the cell formatted as you like, select it and run this short sub.

```
sub find165()
    dim str as string, i as long
    str = activecell.text
    for i = 1 to len(str)
        debug.print ascw(mid(str, i, 1))
    next i
end sub
```

Look at the VBE's Immediate window for the ASCII dec code of each character displayed in the cell.

Comment: It still not ok,

Comment: This doesn't work because the cell does not containg the YEN symbol, it is applied visually only since the cell has accounting format.

Comment: @jamheadart - Actually, you would be wrong on that point. You would be right if I was looking at the range.value or range.value2 but the range.text is the cell's **displayed text** and that includes any symbols added by a currency number format.

Comment: Hmm well in that case I'm not sure - I tried it and it didn't work but let me make sure I've got `.Text` - I wonder if OP is using the `.Text` property also

Comment: Put 100 in any cell and format that cell as a currency with the ¥ symbol. Select that cell then put `cbool(InStr(1, activecell.Text, Chr(165)))` in the VBE's Immediate window and hit enter.

Comment: I tested against .Text, .Value, .NumberFormat and you're correct I get hit, mis, hit

Comment: Thanks @jamheadart. Good to know I'm not any crazier than usual.

Comment: @Jeeped AscW(Mid(strText, 1, 1)) =165, but InStr(1, strText, Chr(165)) still return 0

Comment: This may be the same thing but try `InStr(1, strText, ChrW(165))',

Comment: Your regional system must be treating the symbol as a 2 byte unicode character.

Comment: Unless there is some very special reason to use the user's default character encoding, use Unicode's UTF-16 encoding (`ChrW` and `AscW`). VBA/VB4/VB5/VB6/VB.NET use UTF-16 for strings and must convert the Chr and Asc to/from UTF-16. [BTW—the user's default character encoding is almost certainly not ASCII.] Normally you don't want programs to behave differently based on user settings, espcially very old ones that they might not understand or even know about.

Comment: "¥" is the [Unicode codepoint U+00A5](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A5/index.htm). In UTF-16, codepoints <U+10000 take one code unit and its numeric value is equal to the codepont's numeric value; So `ChrW(&H00A5)`. Same as 195 but it's easier to recognize and reference in hexadecimal.